# Approach for developing software that will need to be ported to multiple mobile platforms in the future

Tags: design, c, mobile, multi-platform

I am currently doing the preliminary design for a new product my company will be pushing out soon. We will start on Android, but then we will need to quickly develop the IPhone, IPad.... and then the Windows 8 ports of the application.

Basically the only code that wouldn't be reusable is the view specific code and the multimedia functions. This will be an SIP client (of course the user of the app will not know this) with several bells and whistles for our own business specific purposes.

My initial thought is to develop all of the engine in C and provide a nice API for the C library since JAVA and .NET will allow native invoking, and I should just be able to directly link to the C lib in objective-C.

Is there a better approach for vast code reuse which also remains close to the native platform? I.e. I don't want dependencies such as Mono-droid and the like or complicated interpreter/translator schemes.

I don't mind re-coding the view(s) for each platform, but I do not want to have multiple versions of the main engine. Also, if I want to have some good abstraction mechanisms (like I would in say, C++) is this possible? I have read that C++ is not allowed for the IPad and Iphone devices.

I would love to handle the media decoding in the C library, but I assume that this will be platform dependent so that probably will not be an option either. Any ideas here?

Comment: `I don't want dependencies such as Mono-droid` -- That's too bad.  It's probably the most promising approach for your objectives.

Comment: I have been looking at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to build a single thin mobile app that will compile across mobile platforms.  I planned on utilizing REST based web services and maintaining nearly all business logic at the server, with only the need for views and presentation logic at the mobile side.

Comment: @maple_shaft That could be a great strategy for other apps, but I could hardly use REST to implement an SIP EndPoint.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that is more of a business decision, and experience, than it is a lack of fondness for the technology. I go on the belief that functions vital to your business should not have dependencies. I don't like having to tell my employer that the reason their prize Windows app has a bug in it, caused by a quirk in .NET, can't be fixed or improved. Even more-so with MONO. I love OSS, but when my ass is on the line, I want complete control over the vital business functionality. Also, I don't care for build mechanisms that are difficult to automate.

Comment: @JonathanHenson `I love OSS, but when my ass is on the line, I want complete control over the vital business functionality.` Suit yourself but most of us aren't writing systems of such high importance that this absurd amount of low level control is necessary.  C as a language is rarely necessary and difficult for just anybody off the street to maintain.  Smarter business decisions are ones where architectural decisions are made that take advantage of well solved issues to save development time and reduce complexity while maintaining low coupling. It sounds as if you want best of both worlds.

Comment: @JonathanHenson Does your software run on its own operating system? No? Oh.. then you can't be in complete control. Everything that is high-levelish has a dependency of some sort that you can't control.

Comment: @marco-fiset You are taking me beyond my intention. I have no problem using the NATIVE interface of the platform. I also don't mind dependencies when it is something that is not vital to the problem domain. I also don't mind higher level languages ( In fact no part of me prefers C for any platform other than *nix). However, I would rather the platform independence be achieved through a good design, than I would through a third party dependency.

Comment: @maple_shaft I am only referring to core business issues here. I use third party stuff all of the time for non-vital functionality. But from a business perspective, you are placing the future of your company in the hands of someone else. Also, the number of dependencies vs platform independence are usually inversely related.

Comment: @JonathanHenson I can respect this mindset, but again avoiding the third party dependency for well solved problems is only a good idea when your solution directly seeks to compete with the third party dependency in its exact same problem domain.  This leaves you as the developer to have more time to address actual business concerns rather than interesting technical challenges (unless of course the interesting technical challenge IS your business concern).

Comment: @maple_shaft I believe we agree. Now, everyone else, any ideas on how I can best achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/ says it does have C++ compilers for native development.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, Ok, I'll hear you out. I do have some questions though. How easily does this port to IOS and Windows? Does everything transfer or is there more coding necessary? What about the multimedia libs?

Comment: @maple_shaft I do think that mono droid may be an option, since my core function is not portability but the SIP and multimedia presentation. I am going to download the free trial and see how well it works.

Comment: Alas, I'm not an expert; I'm exploring these options myself.  But I've heard good things about Xamarin.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and I've heard bad things about them - they're quick to promote themselves (obviously) but be wary fo the information they do not give you (eg performance stats will be in  their favour for the few results they publish). Anyway, check out the pricing model - you don't want to be paying per-device licence fees.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Thanks for the info.  I didn't know they charged per-device fees; that's pretty much a non-starter.  How do they enforce that throught the Apple store?

Comment: I've worked with an enterprise that needed both competitive performance and cross-platform portability.  Their solution was also an engine in C, plus multiple platform-specific GUI skinnings, mobile, PC, and even custom hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are approaching for SIP client, and for the same PJSIP is providing a great library for using SIP feature at client end.

I have also implemented similar application, and for the same, I have create a C code which was handling all my objectives. And then as per iOS and Android platform for background tasks handling and for providing all the native UI implementation, I have done native app development in Objective-C and Java respectively.

Then in iOS, there is no problem for using C code, and for Android I have used JNI-integration.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [Apache Cordova](https://incubator.apache.org/cordova/) (was phonegap) which allows you a cross-platform HTML5/js based GUI. The interesting part to me was that all the code is packaged into the client rather than be run as a client/webserver model (though, obviously you can still talk to a network server for data).
I know a HTML5 gui isn't going to be quite as snappy as a native one, but performance isn't a major concern for most GUIs unless you have specific requirements like gaming.

For access to your crosss-platform C API, Cordova allows you to write a [plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) to call the native code.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe's been doing work in cross-compiling ActionScript for different phone platforms. I'm Pretty sure Flash can compile down to Android and iOS now, as well as AIR (which might get you Windows Phone); I'm not sure how well this will work for SIP protocol-wise, but I'd think it'd support media pretty well. (But then I've not done any development in this area.) The Flash player has limited system access but I hear AIR's support is a lot better, so you might be able to use some decent libs.

**Edit:**

[AIR app for Android](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac25d3d8c712b2d86751e-8000.html)

[AIR app for iOS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f3cb56e2a12cc36970aa-8000.html)